# Way to get detailed listing of all Pages properties in OneNote?

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I have the latest OneNote on Windows 10. I'm trying to create a list of all my Pages in all the Notebooks. One line per Page, showing it's Name, Section and Notebook plus created date. As it's for import into (say) excel, be nice to have it delimited, say with # chars.

```
Nice Wines#Entertainment#Home Notebook#2021-10-01T06:57:32+10:00
```

I really only know Python and PowerShell. Is there any sample code you can suggest or another way to get this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I installed this [PowerShell module](https://github.com/wightsci/OneNoteUtilitiesGraph) and then another Stack Overflow user [helped me get over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69422731/powershell-object-within-object-extract-property-values-and-export-to-csv) another hurdle when using it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).