# Powershell : Object within Object - extract Property values (and export to CSV) - OneNoteUtilitiesGraph

Tags: powershell, onenote

Still fairly new to PowerShell and trying to get a list of all my OneNote pages within a given Section and Notebook...and into a CSV. I'm nearly there, but the final bits are eluding me. I've tried a few things:

I'm using https://github.com/wightsci/OneNoteUtilitiesGraph

```
# This my 'ffmpeg etc' Section. Get its Page(s) info:
$sPages = Get-MgUserOnenoteSectionPage -OnenoteSectionId "0-nnnn" -UserId "bbbb@yyyy.com"

# What do we have available to us?
$sPages | Get-Member
```

Shows (subset):

```
Title                Property              string Title {get;set;}
CreatedDateTime      Property              System.Nullable[datetime] CreatedDateTime {get;set;}
ParentSection        Property              Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Models.IMicrosoftGraphOnenoteSection ParentSection {get;set;}
```

So the last one is Object within an Object?? Anyway, picking some at random and checking some values

```
$sPages[3].Title
Cut a video (lossless) with no re-encoding

$sPages[3].ParentSection.DisplayName
ffmpeg etc
```

But

```
Foreach($s in $sPages) { $s | select Title, CreatedDateTime,ParentSection.DisplayName }
```

Has no value for ParentSection.DisplayName:

```
Title                                                           CreatedDateTime        ParentSection.DisplayName
-----                                                           ---------------        -------------------------
Powershell (ffmpeg) to split media file by times.csv            28/10/2020 10:01:02 AM
Series of numbered images to a video                            6/04/2019 9:35:33 PM
Fuji camera - Timelapse (of cool change, clouds)                6/04/2019 9:36:27 PM
```

What's the correct way to do this, particularly if I want to end up saving these 3 property values to a CSV file? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) for this to get the Displayname of the ParentSection as property of the same object(s)

Try:

```
foreach($s in $sPages) { 
    $s | Select-Object Title, CreatedDateTime,
                       @{Name = 'ParentSection'; Expression = { $_.ParentSection.DisplayName }}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I needed.

Comment: @dwids Thanks. If you feel my answer solved your problem, please mark the question 'done' by clicking the large checkmark icon on the left of the answer. This also helps others with a similar question finding it more easily.

Comment: Ok @Theo. Thanks for the instructions. Done!